# Are domain models immutable by definition?

Tags: domain-driven-design

That is, is there ever a case where a domain model should be available for modification outside of its creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Value objects](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/135) are usually immutable. [Entities](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/109) on the other hand don't have to be immutable. For example your domain can have an Order entity and it is allowed to add line items or change delivery address.

Comment: Thinking about this the next day, your answer, of course, makes sense. I wasn't seeing the trees for the forest.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Dmity's answer, I am assuming that you mean the design of the model as a whole, not the individual entities at runtime.

The answer to this is yes. In fact it this is the whole point of domain modeling. The business model will change over time (this is inevitable - business must adapt to survive) and the model must evolve to match it. Domain modeling combined with agile development techniques takes this into consideration. The trick is to design your domain model so that it can evolve.

Comment: A valid interpretation given my poor wording, and good to know nonetheless.